# Transforming a list with xparse

Tags: xparse

I would like to be able to turn a list `A,B,C` into `A \\ B \\ C`, where A, B, C are LaTeX expressions. It would be quite simple to do with a package like `xstring`, but for the possibility that A, B or C contain a comma. So I thought of using `xparse`,writing some code like `{>{\SplitList{,}}m}`.

Unfortunately not only it didn't work, but even trying such a simple thing as:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\foo%
{>{\SplitList{,}}m}%
{\ProcessList{#1}{#1 X}
.......................
\foo{a,b,c}
```

just produces:

[image]

I expected `aXbXcX`. I really don't understand what's happening, nor what `ProcessList` does.

Another problem is that up to now, I've no idea how to indicate the replacement of the separating commas with newline commands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\ProcessList` doesn't allow inline functions like you've written; the interface expects a single macro to process each subsequent item of the list:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}
\DeclareDocumentCommand \foo { >{\SplitList{,}} m }
 {
  \ProcessList{#1}{\processfoo}
 }
\newcommand\processfoo[1]{#1X}

\foo{a,b,c}
\end{document}
```

The way that you have written it, `\ProcessList{#1}{#1 X}`, results in receiving arguments like:

```
\ProcessList{a,b,c}{a,b,c X}
```

and (for whatever reason) this is how you end up with the unexpected output in your question.

Answer (score 4):

The `stringstrings` package is set up to conveniently manipulate character stings.  It has a limited ability to manipulate macro strings like `\\`.  In this MWE, I first show (ABC) the conversion involving `\\`.  For the second example (DEF), it shows the one-line equivalent if the characters involved are not macros.  The third output (cde) merely shows that `\\` has been properly restored by the `\decodetoken`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\begin{document}
\encodetoken{\\}
\convertchar[e]{A,B,C}{,}{\\}
\retokenize{\thestring}
\thestring
\decodetoken{\\}

\convertchar{D,E,F}{,}{X}

c\\d\\e
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In response to the OP's comment about the need to stack inside the `matrix` environment, I post this addendum to see if a `tabstackengine` alternative would suffice for stacking matrix-like matter?  Here, it is shown using commas as the end-of-line delimiter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\setstackEOL{,}
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\setstackgap{L}{1.3\baselineskip}
\tabularLongstack{rl}{
x =&u^2, y=&v^2, z=&w^2
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve my specific problem: the conversion result must be `A\\B\\C`. To make it more clear, the result must be the argument of the matrix environment, and the `\\` are supposed to denote row change.

Comment: @Bernard Please see addendum to my answer and let me know if there is fruit to be plucked.

Comment: @ Steven B. Segletes: Not to be plucked this time, because it has to be used as a sort of "comment" on the right side of a matrix environment, and the vertical spacing between the lines isn't quite the same. This can be adjusted by hand, but I don't see any automatic way. Thank you for your answer; it helped me to understand much better how (tab)stackengine works.